# Is it common in the previous yugas for a women to have multiple husbands? Like Draupadi had

Tags: history, women, itihasa, mahabharata

Draupadi had five husbands but no where in the Mahabharatam its described as out of the ordinary, as of my knowledge, or its described as a sin. Is it common in those eras to have multiple husbands just like men having multiple wives? Is society more broad minded and men and women are equal in all aspects?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was unusual but not disrespected when a women has multiple husbands. In Draupadi's case, the reason behind all the Pandavas marrying multiple husbands was due to dharma and the previous life. The Pandavas were forced to marry her because they were forced to follow their mother's order, which is "Share the Prize." In Draupadi's case, her previous self asked Lord Shiva for a husband 5 times, causing the 5 Pandavas marrying her. Here is my [evidence](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html).

Comment: I would also add that Ganga also had multiple husbands at the same time.

Comment: I also wanted to add Tara because he married Sugreeva and Vali.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know the story part. But what i was looking at is the societal structure and the way  people viewed these kind of things in those days.

Comment: People viewed it as unusual and weird.